# Reduce GPU memory usage on matrix multiplication in Tensorflow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 matrices of shapes

```
    a: [1, 3, 3, 512, 512]
    b: [1, 14, 14, 3, 3, 512,1]
```

The output is obtained by

```
    output = tf.multiply(a,b)
```

and has shape

```
    output: [1, 14, 14, 3, 3, 512, 512]
```

This operation alone takes around 5GB of GPU memory. I would like to know if there is any way to reduce this memory consumption (since I will be having much larger matrices for the same operation in the future).

I tried a workaround by converting both `a` and `b` to half precision. This also did not help in reducing the memory usage.

It would be great to know if there are any tricks in Tensorflow that I can utilize do to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `tf.GPUOption` to control GPU memory usage. By default, tf occupies lots of GPU memory even if you don't build any computation graph.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GPUOptions for more. Typically, you may want to use `allow_growth` or `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` property.

Comment: I want to reduce memory usage of the multiplication process.
I am already using both these properties you have mentioned.

Comment: If your matrices are really large, you may want to pin these matrices on CPU to reduce GPU memory consumption.

Comment: Perhaps, that seems to be the only hack although having to let go of speed

Comment: isnt there a sub-matrix multiplication option? it would certainly let it use much less memory.

Comment: I don't know = =